# WordPress Page Length Limit

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a landing page in WordPress, the client asked for about 10 sections. I have designed about 8 of them, but now, every new content I add (using page builder) gets deleted after saving. I don't get any error message - just "Page Updated".

Is there a page length limit for WordPress pages

Some PHP info:

```
max_execution_time  180
max_file_uploads    20
max_input_nesting_level 64
max_input_time  60
max_input_vars  10000
memory_limit    256M
open_basedir    no value
```

Thanks

Comment: do you see the new sections in edit area? or does it get deleted from the admin edit page as well?

Comment: They all disappear, in both ends. Feels like there is a length limit to the page itself. I have tried to duplicate the page and edit the copy, also tried to start from scratch, in both scenarios I reached to the limit and any further content I upload get deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after 24 hours of troubleshooting, I was able to fix the issue by adding the following values to php.ini

```
suhosin.post.max_vars = 10000
suhosin.request.max_vars = 10000
```

The hosting company uses the Suhosin extension and it had it's suhosin.post_max_var and suhosin.request_max_vars set too low.

More info here: https://suhosin.org/stories/configuration.html

Comment: Ho @orenja kindly mark this as answered. I don't mind if you mark your own answer, this is only for cleanup :)

Answer (score 0):

**The OP solve this issue.**

The hosting company uses the Suhosin extension and it had it's suhosin.post_max_var and suhosin.request_max_vars set too low.

More info here: https://suhosin.org/stories/configuration.html

Comment: Hey Keith, thanks for your feedback.I'm not trying to create a new page, I am editing an existing page. Seems the page reached to its content limit, every time I try to add more content the new content gets delete and the old one remains.

Comment: I understand. Thanks. How big is this page then? What's the word count (more or less). WP doe snot limit this but there's other aspects whihc will affect you...php and mysql too. These should throw some exceptions. Add this to wp-config "define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );" and try saving again (after refresh)

Comment: Thanks Keith. I have already enabled the Debug option, but it didn't help. I'm using a page builder therefore can't count the words. I've checked with the theme provider and been told that it is server settings, while my server provider is useless. Just to get an impression of the page's length - here is a link to the landing page: (http://www.etecpay.com)

Comment: Sorry didn't notice the reply. Orenja, I have several WP sites with a lot larger landing pages and more content. This shouldn't be an issue with either WP, PHP or MySQL. But I don't know what you mean with "PageBuilder" Can you send me a link to it. Also, if you want you can contact directly so that i can help and then post the answer here for everyone. Find me on keith-mifsud.me